# How to schedule HttpRequest in Netty channel?

Tags: java, http, netty

I need to make several requests using one connection (http keep-alive) and I'd like to add delay between them. Right now in my last handler I write next HttpRequest in channel after LastHttpContent from previous request is received:

```
@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpObject msg) {
   ...
   if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {
      ...
      ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(nextHttpRequest);
      ...
   }
}
```

I suppose that using `Thread.sleep` will block the whole netty reactor so I'm looking for a correct way to delay write in channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule a task to write the message using the ChannelContext's executor:

```
public class ScheduledHttpWriter extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpObject> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpObject msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {
            ctx.executor().schedule(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(outBoundMessage);
                }
            }, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }               
    }

}
```